# Use bash variable in substitution command with this formatting, with JSON

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script where one of the part in a command changes from time to time. 
So I tried to change the script, so we could ask for it, or change at one part only, etc., but can't really make it. 
 
If I write this, it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
changing_stuff='"Active-2021-xy Part YX"'
total_number=`Command_xy show base name "Active-2021-xy-yz Part YX" limit 1 --format json | jq '.total'`
```

I've used **'"  "'** because as you see in the original command it requires **" "** for that part.

How could I add the changing_stuff into the middle of the script? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've tried like "^${changing_stuff=}", also
$(command +'$changing_stuff'+ rest of the command) 
and many other ways. Thanks a lot!

Comment: With `"$changing_stuff"`?

Comment: @renaud-pacalet you should mark it as an answer ;)

Comment: Hmm, your question is probably a duplicate of many others about bash parameters expansion. So, what I should do if I had time, is search for the most appropriate duplicate and suggest to close your question. This is the best thing to do, I think, to avoid having too many variants of the same question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. There's no need to add quotes into your `changing_stuff` variable. Putting quotes around the variable when you use it causes the whole value (including the spaces) to be passed as a single argument to `Command_xy`.

```
#!/bin/bash
changing_stuff='Active-2021-xy Part YX'
total_number=`Command_xy show base name "$changing_stuff" limit 1 --format json | jq '.total'`
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for the trivial

```
#!/bin/bash
changing_stuff='Active-2021-xy Part YX'
total_number=`Command_xy show base name "$changing_stuff" limit 1 --format json | jq '.total'`
```

The quotes are simply a mechanism for keeping the string with spaces in it as a single argument, in both places.

(Tangentially, you also want to replace the backticks with modern command substitution syntax:)

```
#!/bin/bash
changing_stuff='Active-2021-xy Part YX'
total_number=$(Command_xy show base name "$changing_stuff" limit 1 --format json | jq '.total')
```